# Unable to add the URL of to fetch the data from the api call using openweather

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the function in which I am getting an error .

```
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String? {
        var response:String?
        try {

            response = URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&units=metric&appid=$api").readText(Charsets.UTF_8)

        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            response = null
        }
        return response
    }
```

Error : Expression "URL" of type "String" cannot be invoked as a function.
Can anyone help me I am a newbie in kotlin.

Imports

```
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.lang.Exception
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
 import java.util.*
```

Comment: Could you show your imports?

Comment: @Snoopy added the imports

Comment: if possible, please also upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should not use AsynTask now as it is deprecated, please do try [coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines).

But anyway, as you have not provided the full code of your `doInBackground`, please try the below sample and see if that helps you.

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String? {
        var response: String? = null
        try {
            val url = URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&units=metric&appid=YOUR_API_KEY")
            val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            val stream: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream)
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))
            val builder = StringBuilder()
            var inputString: String?
            while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { inputString = it } != null) {
                builder.append(inputString)
            }
            val topLevel = JSONObject(builder.toString())
            val main = topLevel.getJSONObject("main")
            response = main.getDouble("temp").toString()
            urlConnection.disconnect()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return response
    }
```

Fixed the issue, please see the PR

https://github.com/anshmishra010/Weather-App-Kotlin/pull/1

Code in action after fix

[image]

Comment: the one you have in your question snippet is full code?

Comment: if yes, then you have a lot of issues with that, just converting URL to string will not make your API get executed, Please try the code sample I shared and let me know

Comment: From this you may have a better reference

Comment: let me see the repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233073/discussion-between-ansh-mishra-and-dinkarkumar).